# native implementation of call() method in javascript

Tags: javascript

I was try to do the native implementation of call method in javascript. Here we need to handle the object which we pass in the call function and additional params. i handle the additional params using `eval()` method. is there any efficient way to do the native `call()` function implementation. here is my code

```
var name = {
    name: "JavaScript", 
  version: "6",
}   

function printName(location, district){
    alert(this.name + ", " + this.version + ", " + location + ", " + district);
}

Function.prototype.myCall = function(...args){
  var param = args.slice(1),
      paramLength = param.length, 
      paramString = "JSONarg.myFun(";
  for(var i = 1; i <= paramLength; i++){
    paramString += "args["+i+"],";
  }
  paramString += ")";

  if(typeof this != 'function'){
    throw new Error(this + " is not a Function");
  }

  var JSONarg =  {
    ...args[0],
    myFun: this
  }
  return eval(paramString);
}

printName.myCall(name, "Chrome", "browser");
```

Comment: Why would you want to do this?

Comment: want to understand how call function is work behind the screen

Comment: Well to truly do that you'd have to be looking at the internal implementation, which definitely does not involve `eval()`. It's almost certainly not JavaScript code.

Answer (score 1):

Without call.

```
Function.prototype.myCall = function(context, ...args){
    this.apply(context, args)
}
```

but i see no reason for this

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your `call` method implementation is a ES3 version because you create a params list string and use `eval` to execute the function. But you also have used rest params here which proves that the browser supports ES6. So we can use spread syntax to make things easier.

In a word, if you have to implement the method using ES3, you can do it like this:

```js
// ES3 viersion
Function.prototype.myCall = function(thisArg){
   if(typeof this != 'function'){
      throw new Error('the caller must be a function')
   } 
   if(thisArg === null || thisArg === undefined){
      thisArg = window
   } else {
      thisArg = new Object(thisArg)
   }
   const args = []
   for(var i = 1;i < arguments.length;i ++){
      args.push('arguments[' + i + ']')
   }
   thisArg.fn = this
   const res = eval('thisArg.fn(' + args + ')')
   delete thisArg.fn
   return res
}
```

The version above is similar to yours. But if ES6 is allowed to use, you can do it more efficiently like this:

```js
// ES6 verison
Function.prototype.myCall = function(thisArg,...args){
  if(typeof this != 'function'){
    throw new Error('the caller must be a function')
  }
  if(thisArg === null || thisArg === undefined){
    thisArg = window
  } else {
    thisArg = new Object(thisArg)
  }
  thisArg.fn = this
  const res = thisArg.fn(...args)
  delete thisArg.fn
  return res 
}
```

However, what's notable is that both of these 2 versions aren't standard implementations.